# Read a very long console input in C++

Tags: c++, io, iostream, cin, getline

I'm trying to read a list of numbers (space delimited) from the console using std::cin. When the input line is longer than 1023 characters, the first "cin >> list[i]" in the following small working example never returns:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {

    vector<int> list(200,0);
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
        cin >> list[i];
        cout << '-';
        cin.clear();
        if(list[i]==0) break;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

This code fails for the following input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 000 000
```

but works when you remove the last three zeros. I tried getline() as well without success.

EDIT:
An interesting side note: if I end my console input with a backspace before hitting return, it works even when the length is >1023. Maybe that means something to someone? I usually copy paste the input, could that be contributing to the error?

Comment: This might be a limitation of the console's text input buffer.

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/RKcoJD

Comment: @MikeNakis it works there because the input is redirected. My guess is that OPs console has a fixed input buffer of 1K.

Comment: @vsoftco Sure, but I would find it incredibly lame (literally incredibly, as in, not able to believe it) that the standard library of his runtime environment actually **hangs** because it cannot handle a text line which is too long.

Comment: @MikeNakis maybe the terminal itself has some kind of issue sending its input buffer to the standard input stream. I find it very hard to believe that the problem lies in the libc++ or libstdc++. But I have to say I haven't seen this behaviour before, probably because I never input more than 2-3 characters ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that your console cannot read more than 1024 characters (same happens on my terminal in OS X, probably that's how long the input buffer is). Try putting the input into a file, and redirect the program's input, like `./a.out < in.txt`. It works this way.

PS: related: https://superuser.com/questions/264407/macosx-10-6-7-cuts-off-stdin-at-1024-chars

Comment: Dude, you have 6,666 reputation!

Comment: Thanks! I'm on OS X too, using xcode, so perhaps that is why.

Comment: It seems to be a "problem" with OS X terminal, see the updated edit. Also, iTerm has the same issue.

Comment: I'm convinced this is the answer. I cannot replicate the issue in other environments (such as online compilers). Thank you!